# Deploying spring boot mvc to remote tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to this, and this is my first time trying to deploy any webapp on remote server.
I have purchased a private tomcat and jvm plan and since few days i am trying to deploy my application which is running perfectly fine locally. but not on remote tomcat. my local jdk version is same as it is on remote server.
this time just to test I have developed a very simple "Hello world" spring boot starter web application, which is having a @RestController and a @RequestMapping method, to show a String as "Hi there!"
It has nothing apart from it, I have done steps as it was suggested by my service providers and uploaded it to webapp directory of remote tomcat, then stopped and restarted remote tomcat. but in the Browser when i try to open my website, it shows nothing, not even error, Just a plain white background.
I really have no idea whats going wrong , can any one help ?

Comment: Are you seeing any error in browser console? (F12)

Comment: Hi, it says I am requesting for https , while I dont have ssl so can request http only.. Now I have not done any configuration for this, spring boot did it internally for me..yes my simple app did work later with correct repackaging through maven.. but now my original app is not working because of the above error

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, you have to reconfigure your project to produce a WAR
>   file and declare the embedded container dependencies as "provided".
>   This ensures that the relevant embedded container dependencies aren’t
>   included in the WAR file.

You can see a configuration guide for maven and gradle here

https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

And a guide to spring boot applications

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: HI thanks, I checked the links, actually I am packaging it this way, a quick debug in firefox said its because I am requesting url as https request while i can access to only http..as I have not taken ssl certificate yet, I dont even know If i configured my app for https, may be spring boot did it internally, Now I am totally blank

Comment: please add the log of the server

Comment: HI Sorry for Late reply, I was away because of a festival here. in catalina.out in my remote log directory I found this error  "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml.

Comment: Its a spring boot thymeleaf application packaged as war, I have checked for closing of any tags, and there is no error regarding that, I have also added @ComponentScan("com.basepackage") annotation to my MVCConfig class. on local pivotal of sts app is working fine, but on remote tomcat its not showing anything